# extjs can't display correctly

Tags: javascript, extjs

it's two thirty AM in here and i am still stuck with a problem.I am writing a simple demo but the page doesn't display the way i expected.At first i tried extjs6.2.0-gpl,then i tried ext.js3.4.0.Neither of them seem to work.

**With ext.js3.4.0:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="./ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script src="./ext-3.4.0/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script src="./ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script>
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert("ss");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

folder hierarchy:
[image]

display:
[image]

***with extjs6:***

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="./ext6/resources/theme-classic-all.css" />
    <script src="ext6/ext-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="ext6/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert("ss");
        });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

folder hierarchy:
[image]

display:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try to use cdnjs url to test if you get the right result.Here is the sample code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         Ext.onReady(function() {
          Ext.MessageBox.alert("ss");
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for answering!! stackoverflow is really a good community.There are always pople willing to offer  assistance to  a newbie!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.Just add rel="stylesheet" and type="stylesheet" attributes when you reference extjs!!    f**k it !! but these attributes aren't necessary when i was using other js plugins!!!